# Ack packet construct with GPS

Tags: c, sockets, server, gps

I am running a server in C to listen to GPS devices . According to the manufacturer's specs, server should respond to login  packet and heartbeat packets in the form of acknowledgement  packets . The server acknowledgement packet is 10 bytes long. I am trying to build the packet as follows:

```
/* 
packet structure
start bit - 2 bytes ( 0-1)
packet length - 1 byte(2)
Protocol no - 1 byte(3)
info serial no - 2 bytes(4-5)
check sum - 2 bytes(6-7)
stop_bit - 2 bytes(8-9)
TOTAL 10 bytes

*/  
 unsigned char ack[11];
 ack[0] = 0x78;
 ack[1] = 0x78;
 ack[2] = 0x05; //packet length
 ack[3] = buffer[3]; //protocol no
 ack[4] = buffer[size-6]; //info serial 1st byte where 
 //size is incoming packet length
 ack[5] = buffer[size-5]; //info serial 2nd byte
 // crc16 is the value coming from checksum function
 ack[6] = ack[6] =(crc16>>8) & 0xFF; //chksum byte1
 ack[7] = crc16 & 0xFF;//chksum byte 2
 ack[8] = 0x0D; //stop byte1
 ack[9] = 0x0A; //stop byte2
```

However, I am not receiving any response from server beyond login packet. it would be helpful to get quick responses

Comment: `unsigned char ack[11]`, `ack[2] = 0x05; //packet length`, `TOTAL 10 bytes`... 5, 10 or 11 bytes? How do you send the `ack` packet? Does the specification have an example that you could try to implement?

Comment: It is 10 bytes  Please see the comment before the code  for explanation. I have assigned 11 bytes to ack as I thought null byte has to be added. But that is not working either .

Comment: What does the specification tell? How do you send the packet?

Comment: Specification tells the same as described above . I am reproducing a below:  1 .Start Bit Fixed value in HEX 0x78 0x78.  2 Packet Length Length = Protocol Number + Information Content + Information Serial Number + Error Check, totally (5+N)Bytes, because the Information Content is a variable length field. 3. Protocol Number : 1byte 4. Information Serial Number: 2bytes for the serial number of the first GPRS data  5. Error Check: 2bytes  6. Stop Bit :Fixed value in HEX 0x0D 0x0A.   Information content is value N = 0 since it is a response packet. I am sending it through socket write function